# JSP content coming up twice in web page source

Tags: html, jsp, w3c-validation

In my web page source, the JSP content is coming up twice. While validating my web page source from W3C validator I am getting the duplicate ID error.
I am not able to understand that why some HTML contents from my JSP are coming up twice in my web page?
Below is the one of the HTML content which is being repeated in web page source.`

```
        <form id="searchBarForm" name="searchBarForm" class="form-default form-search">
        <input type="hidden" id="pageNumber" name="pageNumber" value='1' />
            <div class="grid-holder">
                <div id="invalidMilesMsgSearchBar" role="alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-static hide">
                            <p>Please enter a valid points range.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row grid-search grid-search-1">
                    <div class="col-main col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <label>Search
                                    rewards </label>
                            </div>
                            <input id="searchKeyword" name="keyword" type="text" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Search across all rewards" value='' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row grid-search grid-search-2">
                    <div class="col-main col-sm-9 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <label>and / or by points
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-range">
                                <input type="tel" id="maskBarFromMile" name="fromMile" class="form-control inp-from quantity-input maskBarFromMile"
                                    placeholder="" value='' />
                                <div class="sep">-</div>
                                <input type="tel" id="maskBarToMile" name="toMile" class="form-control inp-to quantity-input maskBarToMile" value='' />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-main col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="bttn">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="searchRexButton" class="btn btn-primary abtn-search">Go </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row grid-search grid-search-3 hide">
                    <div class="col-main col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                        <p class="text-label">
                            Let us inspare you with our Reward Finder
                        </p>
                        <div class="bttn">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Reward Finder
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: This is not clear for understanding only posting jsp part of your code. Please post whole code.

Answer (score 0):

please write your jsp code that part generate this html, I think there is a problem in your jsp code and cause generate twice html code...

Comment: On further digging, I found out my JSP was included twice in some other JSP file. This was the reason for the error. Thanks for the help..!